# Как выбрать переменную через логический оператор?

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
$a = (object)["ttl2"=>15];
$b=21;
$c= $a->ttl1 || $b;
echo $c;
```

Ожидаемое поведение: Так-как `$a->ttl1` null. В `$c` должно быть `$b` (21).

Судя по всему, тут php работает по-другому. Я получаю 1 (как я понимаю, результат привидения `true`) к числу.

Как достичь желаемого поведения? Только через `if ($a->ttl1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *PHP* это выглядит так:

```
$c= $a->ttl1 ?? $b;
```

[Оператор объединения с null](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)